# Pointing to a file in GCP located in Google Storage Buckets

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, kubernetes-ingress

I have a link to a public URL in the format of `https://storage.googleapis.com/companyname/foldername/.another-folder/file.txt`

I want to create an ingress rule to create a path to this public file, so that whoever open a specific URL, e.g., https://myapp.mydomain.com/.another-folder/myfile.txt -> it open up above file.

I tried a few different ingress rules such as:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: googlestoragebucket
spec:
  externalName: storage.googleapis.com
  ports:
  - name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 443
  type: ExternalName
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: staging-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: staging-static-ip
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: website-frontend
      port:
        number: 80
  rules:
  - host: myapp.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /.another-folder/
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: googlestoragebucket
            port:
              number: 443
       - pathType: ImplementationSpecific
         backend:
          service:
            name: myactual-app
            port:
              number: 80
```

But I couldn't make it wrok. In this case I've got an error: `Translation failed: invalid ingress spec: service "staging/googlestoragebucket" is type "ExternalName", expected "NodePort" or "LoadBalancer`

I don’t mind any other solutions to achieve the same result in the context of GCP and Kubernetes.

Do you have any ideas?

Looking forward for you suggestions.

Comment: Are you using Google Kubernetes Engine or Kubernetes Open Source?
For the ingress part, did you take a look [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)?

Comment: I’m using Kubernetes on Google Cloud Platform @HectorMartinezRodriguez

Answer (score 1):

Think that you should be able to do it via Cloud External Load Balancer:

Here is some information about that:

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-load-balancer-backend-buckets

Then you can point the ingress to that load balancer:
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features

Another option is use some proxy, la Nginx, there is a post on GitHub about this: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1809